# Is it possible to detect the current garbage collector implementation using mono?

Tags: .net, mono, garbage-collection

We have a assembly provided to us by a third-party that leaks memory when using the boehm GC for mono, but that does not leak when using the S-Gen GC.

When we start the program, we want to warn the user if he's using the "wrong" GC, and to do that we need to detect which one is used.

Is there an API to detect this?

Comment: "that leaks memory when using the boehm GC for mono, but that does not leak when using the S-Gen GC" - curious as to how you made that determination?...

Comment: Trial and error really. When we run it on mono 2.10 with --gc=boehm, memory usage grows unbounded until the system runs out of memory to allocate to the process. With --gc=sgen, memory usage peaks at expected values (which corresponds to file sizes as we read files into memory to process them), and then falls back after file processing is complete.

Comment: sounds like you should report as a bug...

Comment: It may be a bug, or it may just be that the imprecise stack scanner used with boehm pins too many objects, which is as far as I know a known weakness of it.

Comment: What platform are you running on? You could parse out the command line arguments of the mono process... On .NET you can get the arguments of other processes through WMI. Not sure about Linux...

Comment: The program runs on Windows, Linux and OS X, so a cross-platform solution would be best, but I suspect there will be three different platform-specific hacks I'll have to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a specific API, but you can use GC.MaxGeneratio: when using the Boehm GC it will be 0 and higher with the sgen GC.

Comment: This seems to work on linux (mono 2.10.2), but on Windows 7 64bit with mono 2.10.5, GC.MaxGeneration returns 0 for me under both boehm and sgen.

Comment: Windows in that version still didn't have a sgen port. The sgen GC will be available for windows 32 in the next mono release (2.11/2.12).

Comment: Ah, that explains that. Thanks for your help!